# Scroll to the right in element with fixed width and hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have setup an example which has a fixed-width element with hidden overflow, which scrolls to the right end.

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/alp82/pen/DEehl/)

HTML

```
<div class="nowrap">
  <div class="inner">
    START Large container, fixed width, only one row, scrolls to end if overflow happens, -------------------------> END
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40em;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  var $nowrap = $('.nowrap');
  var $inner = $('.inner');
  var width = $inner.width();
  $nowrap.scrollLeft(width);
});
```

### My questions:

1. Is there a way without the need for two nested elements, but have only one element with the same functionality? (maybe with pseudo-elements)
2. Is there a CSS-only way to make the element show the right end of its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see exaclty what you are trying to achieve but for the second issue, you can **float** the parent element left and float the child right so it shows only it's right end.

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fX2T7/)**

Dependeing on the surronding elements in your full project, you might be able to remove the parent element.

---

You can also use **position absolute** to position your element depending on the parent element. (in the following demo I deleted the parent element so the positioning is relative to the viewport).

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fX2T7/3/)**

CSS demo 1 :

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 40em;
    float:left;
}
.inner {
    float:right;
}
```

HTML demo 2 :

```
<div class="inner">START Large container, fixed width, only one row, scrolls to end if overflow happens, -------------------------> END</div>
```

CSS demo 2 :

```
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Your second demo answers both of my questions perfectly. No JavaScript involved and no extra outer element. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I am following you 100% but I gave it a shot.

> Is there a way without the need for two nested elements, but have only one element with the same functionality? (maybe with pseudo-elements)

I don't see why you need `.nowrap` at all here. Those properties can be set on `.inner`.

> Is there a CSS-only way to make the element show the right end of its content?

There's no way to do this with just CSS, but you can set just set a really high number like `$('.inner').scrollLeft(10000000)` and it'll just go all the way to the right.

Here is my demo: http://jsbin.com/garig/1/edit?html,css,js,output